# Ionic 6: Botones extra en la barra de navegación

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework

Resulta que usando Ionic 6 (Vue), me han aparecido 2 botones extra en la barra de navegación (adjunto captura).

[image: Botones extra en la barra de navegacion Android]

Recuerdo que con Ionic 4 no me pasaba esto.

¿Alguien tiene idea de como se pueden desactivar?

Gracias y un saludo.